# Distribution of stopping time for a 2D random walk

Tags: pr.probability, recreational-mathematics

Consider the following process on $\mathbb{C}$:

- Start at the point 1.
- At each step, move by adding $e^{i\theta}$, where $\theta$ is uniformly drawn from $\mathbb{S}^1$.
- Stop at the first positive time $T$ where you move inside the *open* unit disc.

What is the distribution of the stopping times?

*Some notes*:

- $T = 1$ happens 1/3 of the time, by simple geometry.
- $T = 2$ happens 1/9 of the time, by evaluating an explicit integral.  (Let $g(T,x)$ be the probability that starting at $x$ you will hit the unit disc with exactly stopping time $T$, you can write an integral relating $g(T+1,x)$ to $g(T,x+z)$ with $z\in \mathbb{S}^1$. When $T = 1$ the function is explicitly known by simple geometry. When $T = 2$ and $|x| = 1$ the value can be obtained by direct integration, but for $|x| > 1$ I don't know how to evaluate the integral involved. And hence I also cannot get the exact value for $T = 3$ at $x = 1$. [Later this weekend I may try to evaluate these chain of integrals numerically and provide some more numeric data.])
- Numerical simulations of the random walk seems to suggest that $P(T)$ follows a power rule $T^\alpha$ where $\alpha \approx \log_2(0.4)$. But I only checked up to around $T = 1000$, as the numerical simulation is not very efficient.

Comment: whats ur question? $\lim_{T \to \infty} \log P(T)/\log T$?

Comment: Weird. My guess would be that the decay of $P(T)$ is the same as for the hitting time of a disk by the 2-D Brownian motion, that is, $T^{-1} (\log T)^{-2}$, see Byczkowski–Małecki–Ryznar 2013, [DOI:10.1007/s11118-012-9296-7](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11118-012-9296-7).

Comment: On a second thought, these two functions are [rather hard to distinguish](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7Bt%5E%28Log%5B0.4%5D%2FLog%5B2%5D%29%2C+5%2Ft%2FLog%5Bt%5D%5E2%7D%2C%7Bt%2C10%2C1000%7D%5D)... :-)

Comment: Not _exactly_ the same question, but close: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/612392/241

Comment: @mathworker21: any description of the asymptotic of $P(T)$ would be great, if $P(T)$ is explicitly known even better.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: you are probably correct about the asymptotics! Can you make your comment an answer?

Comment: Thanks @SteveHuntsman I haven't look at the linked answers in detail there, but I think for that one the person doesn't stop but continues after first return? There's probably a way to convert between the two but not immediately obvious to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the continuous counterpart, if a 2-D Brownian particle is started at $x$ with $|x| > 1$, the density function of the hitting time of the unit disk decays as
$$ \frac{1}{t (\log t)^2} $$
as $t \to \infty$. More precisely, it is comparable to
$$ \frac{|x|-1}{|x|} e^{-(|x|-1)^2/(2t)} \frac{(|x|+t)^{1/2}}{t^{3/2}} \frac{1 + \log |x|}{(1 + \log(1 + \tfrac{t}{|x|})) (|x| + \log t)} \, . $$
with absolute constants in both bounds. This incredibly precise estimate, as well as similar results in higher dimensions, were proved in:

- T. Byczkowski, J. Małecki, M. Ryznar, *Hitting Times of Bessel Processes*. Potential Anal 38, 753–786 (2013). https://doi.org/10.1007/s11118-012-9296-7

I would expect the large-time decay of $P(T)$ is thus similar to $T^{-1} (\log T)^{-2}$.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently the $T$ asymptotics was already known due to Hunt https://www.jstor.org/stable/1992918?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents and the main sharpening in the paper you mentioned is of the spatial dependence.

Comment: Yes, the problem is of course very old — although I did not know about Hunt's paper, thanks for sharing it. TThe paper I mentioned was simply the first one that came to my mind. (The authors are my colleagues and I remember their seminar talk.)

Comment: I only saw Hunt's paper as a reference when I started reading the paper that you linked to. The older work happens to be a little easier for me to digest, this being a bit outside my normal interests.

Comment: I also should thank you for the observation of the similarity between the functions $1/(t \ln(t)^2)$ and $t^{-1.3}$. I was mentally prepared for $t^{-1}$ + corrections, and it just never occurred to me (not being a numerics person) that 1000 is still really damn far from infinity.

Comment: Actually, I would have never expected myself that these two functions could be so similar in the range $[10, 1000]$. That's right, logarithms make asymptotic analysis much more complicated.